# NeoPixel Gradient sweep function

Tags: esp8266, neopixel, ws2812

[image]

I'm trying to create a function that takes two colours and creates a smooth gradient between them one colour at the beginning and one at the end

I just can't figure the math of mixing them evenly

I'm using neopixel library

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways of doing this.

One is to use the H channel of the HSV colour space (as I show in the answer to [this question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/75446/rgb-led-color-control-with-a-single-value/). This would give you a smooth transition between two colours through the pre-defined spectrum of the hue range.

The second is to simply specify two colours and then mix them at different percentages depending on how far along the length you are.

For example, here's a (untested) small function that "mixes" two individual colour channels together and returns the result:

```
uint8_t mix(uint8_t a, uint8_t b, int pct, int range) {
    if (pct <= 0) return a;
    if (pct >= range) return b;
    return (((uint32_t)a * (range-pct)) / range) + (((uint32_t)b * pct) / range);
}
```

`pct` is the led number in your chain, and `range` is the total number of LEDs.

So you could (hypothetically):

```
uint8_t red1 = 0, green1 = 255, blue1 = 0;
uint8_t red2 = 255, green2 = 100, blue2 = 100;

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    uint8_t red = mix(red1, red2, i, 50);
    uint8_t green = mix(green1, green2, i, 50);
    uint8_t blue = mix(blue1, blue2, i, 50);
    setLedColor(i, red, green, blue);
}
```

Comment: Very clever

However, only one LED lights up, sorry I can't debug it myself :<

Comment: My sketch: https://pastebin.com/0fYD6w3y

Comment: the sketch belongs in your question as text, not as a link ... please edit your question ... format the code properly using the `{}` button

Comment: The `50` in my example code is the number of LEDs. Obviously you need to tune that to the actual number of LEDs in your setup.

Comment: I tried both 8 leds and 50 and 7 counting from 0 but i think that even with more leds in sketch more than 1 led would light up

Comment: In the 2nd block of code on this answer, I believe all occurrences of 50 should be a reference to the variable holding the number of LEDs. Without it, you may not be notice the difference between the 8 LEDs depending on your initial color choices.

Also, and I think this may be your main issue -- I use a different NeoPixel library, but I would assume it is likely similar. After setting pixel values, I have to call `strip.show()` before the LEDs reflect the values I want.